# Object expected - jQuery error in IE8 and IE9

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps API v3 and I am having a problem with IE8,9. Note that in other browsers it works flawlessly, no errors (on page or console).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    var target = jQuery('.google-map'),
        desiredheight = target.parent().siblings('div').height();

    target.height(desiredheight);

});

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    var target = jQuery('.google-map'),
        myLatlng, myOptions, map, infowindow, marker, mapStyle, styledMap;

    if (target.length > 0) {

        myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(target.attr('data-latitude'), target.attr('data-longitude'));

        myOptions = {
            zoom: parseInt(target.attr('data-zoom'), 10) || 6,
            center: myLatlng,
            html: target.attr('data-title'),
            mapTypeControl: false,
            popup: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(target[0], myOptions);

        mapStyle = [{
            stylers: [{
                saturation: -100
            }]
        }, {
            featureType: 'road',
            elementType: 'geometry',
            stylers: [{
                lightness: 100
            }, {
                visibility: 'simplified'
            }]
        }, {
            featureType: 'road',
            elementType: 'labels',
            stylers: [{
                visibility: 'off'
            }]
        }];

        if (mapStyle) {

            styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(mapStyle, {
                name: 'InspireThemes'
            });
            map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
            map.setMapTypeId('map_style');

        }

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: target.attr('data-content')
        });

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: target.attr('data-title')
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

            infowindow.open(map, marker);

        });

    }

});
```

I am getting error report on line 72 which would be this:

```
myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng( target.attr( 'data-latitude' ), target.attr( 'data-longitude' ) );
```

Now, I tried with Google of course, and all of the problems were cause by extra comma at the end of array or object, which of course does not work in IE. But even though my problem does have such syptoms, I can't figure out where I would have extra comma.

I tried with various js tools but no help.

Comment: Actually, I don't think you do have any extra commas. Before I even read that part of your post, the first thing that I looked for was extra commas in your objects/arrays (since it is such a common bug) and it doesn't look like you have any.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I searched, tried deleting part of code, style object etc. but nothing helps at all.

Comment: I don't get an error in IE on [this version of your code](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_JQueryIE_Error.html)

Comment: Ok let me upload the template I am building to my host, give me a minute.

Comment: Issue resolved by uploading to live server, localhost was causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I am not actually familiar with this part of their API, nor do I know your entire use case, but from the rest of your code, I think that the issue is that you did not specify which target to take that attribute from, here:

```
myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng( target.attr( 'data-latitude' ), target.attr( 'data-longitude' ) );
```

It think that it should be:

```
myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng( target[i].attr( 'data-latitude' ), target[i].attr( 'data-longitude' ) );
```

where `i` is the index of the object within `target` that you are taking that attribute from.

(The first element in the array was a jQuery element).
<strike>This would also explain why you are getting the `object expected` error, as you are calling `.attr` on `target`, which is an array of objects, but is not, itself, an object. This may be a bit confusing, as jQuery methods, like `.attr` can be called on a jQuery array, but `target` is not a jQuery array, and even if it was, you would likely not get your expected result.</strike>

**UPDATE**

This is not the answer, but you may need to also call `parseInt` on the `target.attr('data-latitude')` and `target.attr('data-longitude')`.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. I tried your way, and I get erro in the console, something about non existing .attr method.

Also, even when I switch those two methods with direct numbers, I still get the same error in IE.

Comment: Sorry, pressed eneter and sent half of the comment. Check above.

P.S Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Okay, that actually makes sense because your first element in `target` IS a jQuery object and referencing just `target` will reference the first element. I didn't notice that. (I would still suggest you use the index, in case you change the array around). I will look again. In the meantime, can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Ok weird. On fiddle, it works ok in IE9 (in IE8 I get bunch of erros, probably me as I use IETester).

http://jsfiddle.net/eadP6/

Now thats weird :S

Comment: Yeah, those are all actually jsFiddle errors, not yours. Can you make a live demo?

Comment: Just uploading the full template I am building

Comment: Ok it seems that my problem was in localhost. When uploaded on a live server, everything works just fine! Thanks for helping and sorry for the bother :)

Comment: Yup, no worries. I actually was just about to say the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by uploading to live server, localhost was causing problems.

Thanks everyone that helped, I appreciate it!

Comment: Were you testing on a `file:` URL or using a local web server with a `localhost:` URL. I would expect everything in the Maps API to work properly on a `localhost:` URL. (I test this way all the time, either with `localhost:` or using my machine's hostname in the URL.) I wouldn't trust a `file:` URL to run the Maps API properly in all browsers, though.

Comment: I was using localhost. WAMP server.